# Unable to install nuget package into azure function

Tags: c#, azure, function, nuget

I am just starting to use Azure functions in the logic apps.I have created a function that i am trying to use a Nuget package HTMLAgilityPack and getting it install via the console (in classic view). But it mentions that no project found?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [NuGet packages in a 2.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages) and later C# function, upload a `function.proj` file to the function's folder in the function app's file system. Here is an example `function.proj` file that adds a reference to `HtmlAgilityPack` version `1.11.24`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.24" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

And add `using HtmlAgilityPack;` above the code, refer to the snapshot as below:

[image]