# Unable to install Nuget Packages on Azure function

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, azure-functions, html-agility-pack

I need to work with `HTMLAgilityPack` and `Newtonsoft.Json` on my Azure function, and it has become a serious headache for me. Even after installing and referencing all the required packages via `Nuget`, multiple times over the course of many days, nothing seems to be working in my favor.

Below is a piece of my code for reference:

```
    #r "HtmlAgilityPack"

    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    public static SiteMeta GetSiteMeta(string URL)
    {
    SiteMeta siteMeta = new SiteMeta();
    string retImg = "", retDesc = "", retTitle = "", retKeywords = "";
    var getHtmlDoc = new HtmlWeb(); // Need to use this function from HTMLAgility pack
    var document = getHtmlDoc.Load(URL);
    var metaTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
    if (metaTags != null)
    {
        foreach (var sitetag in metaTags)
        {
            if (sitetag.Attributes["property"] != null && sitetag.Attributes["content"] != null && sitetag.Attributes["property"].Value.ToLower() == "og:description")
            {
                retDesc = sitetag.Attributes["content"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/63048380/1584140 a couple of times and many other answers over Stackoverflow as well as other websites, but the only errors I see everywhere are:

```
    run.csx(5,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found
    run.csx(17,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    run.csx(108,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlWeb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Similar thing happens with `Newtonsoft.Json` as well.

This is how my VS project looks like:

[image: Image showing a screenshot of the project from Visual Studio - Solution Explorer]

*Edit July 10 2022: Adding content on .csproj*

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="TimerTrigger1\run.csxc" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="TimerTrigger1\function.proj" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.43" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.5" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="TimerTrigger1/function.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="TimerTrigger1/readme.md">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="TimerTrigger1\run.csx">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

Comment: If you're deploying from source code, and not writing in the portal, you shouldn't need the `#r` reference tag. Is the `HTMLAgilityPack.dll` being built to the `bin` directory locally?

Comment: Also can you add the contents of your `.csproj` to your question please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install nuget package into azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030236/unable-to-install-nuget-package-into-azure-function)

Comment: @user1672994, that's the same question I've quoted answer for in my question above.

Comment: @JamesGould, removing `#r` starts to throw same error for all other required namespaces. And yes the `HtmlAgilityPack.dll` is being built in `bin`. I have also modified the question above by adding content from `.csproj` file.